# Does REGEXP constraint work in orientdb?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Documentation describes possibility to do regexp constraints:

```
ALTER PROPERTY Account.gender REGEXP "[M|F]"
```

I always receive exception:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException:
Cannot find a command executor for the command request: ...
```

Every other thing works. Did you have this problem? How did you fix it? Should I create an issue?

EDIT:

I use version 2.2.18. I was trying to execute this code:

```
CREATE CLASS Account extends V;
CREATE PROPERTY Account.Gender STRING (MANDATORY TRUE, MAX 20, REGEXP "[M|F]");
```

I also don't see regexp option when inspecting scheme in studio. There is everything else: mandatory, read only, not null, min, max, collate, etc... but no regexp.

Comment: which version 2.2.18?

Comment: @wolf4ood yes, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create the Account class and the gender property before doing this request?

This is working :

```
CREATE CLASS Account extends V
CREATE PROPERTY Account.gender STRING
ALTER PROPERTY Account.gender REGEXP "M|F"
```

EDIT :

You actually can't do it in one request (you need to alter the property to add regexp) I don't think it's normal so you can create an issue.

Hope it helps

Comment: All of the sudden it started working. No more OCommandExecutorNotFoundException. I don't know why. With no csv changes. That makes me a bit anxious. Thanks for confirming CREATE + REGEXP don't work in one line. Now I see the issue was created: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6411